# Noise removal from webpages

Tags: java, web, noise

I am trying to do noise removal from web page . but as I am new to this so i don't know from where to start.
so if anybody can give me any information on how to do it , it will be very helpful.

Noise - links , copyright notices etc.

Sudhanshu

Comment: "One man's trash is another man's treasure."

Comment: "One man's signal is another man's ... er ratio?" Claude Shannon before he pinned it all down.

Comment: what do you mean by noise removal? what do you mean by noise? what do you mean by web pages? don't be shy to share the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boilerpipe seems like what you're asking for: http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/

> The boilerpipe library provides algorithms to detect and remove the
>   surplus "clutter" (boilerplate, templates) around the main textual
>   content of a web page.
>
> The library already provides specific strategies for common tasks (for
>   example: news article extraction) and may also be easily extended for
>   individual problem settings.